# Save text from form to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, content-management-system

Im trying to create options page in which the user can input then save data into a few forms and then when saved is added to the database which intern can be read, I'm not really sure how to do this so i'm hoping someone could help.

Thanks

Denver

Comment: So you cannot program at all?

Comment: well i understand the basics but its a learning project and i can implement code. just not sure for this bit

Comment: That will require a few tutorials, Denver. How much of what you just said can you do?

Comment: You should format and phrase your post better. I don't really understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Osiris I'm wondering the best way to save text inputed in a form to a database table so it can be displayed elsewhere

Comment: @Hameed Not quite sure what you mean

Comment: @Denver: `$_POST` + `PDO`. PS: please stop using "the best way" in your phrases - in your case any way is the best one.

Comment: not to get snarky but everyones looking for the best way. 

thanks for the info

Comment: @Denver this is how you take the first step http://bit.ly/SE9s4O

Comment: @Sibu obviously i've googled it and i was hoping there was a way to do it without another php file

Comment: If you have specific concerns/problems/questions, then ask them. If your question is "how to use databases", then please start by yourself with some tutorial or a book. If your question is "how to do X without Y", then please ask that.

Comment: @Denver: the thing is - you're not confident enough to do that in the best way, because you don't even know the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could very easilly just say:

```
<?php
mysql$_connect("databaseserver", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("databasename");
$fname = 'Tim';
$lname = 'Powell';
$email = 'tpowell@powellintellabs.com';
mysql_query("INSERT * INTO table (fname, lname, email) VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$email')");
?>
```

The if(!$connect) just tells you when your web server and database server aren't communication properly.

Answer (score 2):

Inserting data into a database is really quite simple.

try:

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("databaseserver", "username", "password");
if(!$connect)
{
echo 'Error';
}
mysql_select_db("databasename", $connect);
$fname = 'Tim';
$lname = 'Powell';
$email = 'tpowell@powellintellabs.com';
mysql_query("INSERT * INTO table (fname, lname, email) VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$email')");
?>
```

This should insert information into the database "databasename" and the table "table". Also, if you're not familiar with databases, something has to be unique. If you name a column "id" as your primary key and set it to auto increment, it makes it a lot easier. You might want to also look into preventing mysql injection attacks. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: would i have to use the hole connect setup if its in a cms that has file that specifies that?

Comment: A+ for effort! Welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: who was that targeted to? and I presume if it was to me it was sarcastic

Answer (score 1):

Its quite easy and understandable try this..........

> Php code starts here
>
> ?php
>
> $hostname="your host name";
>
> $username="your user name";
>
> $password="your password";
>
> $con = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
>
> if (!$con)
>    {
>
> die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
>   }
>
> mysql_select_db("your db name", $con);
>
> $sql="insert into tablename (colname1, colname2, colname3, colname4..)
>   values
>   ('$_POST[colname1]','$_POST[colname2]','$_POST[colname3]','$_POST[colname4]')";
>
> if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
>
> {
>
> die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
>
> }
>
> echo "1 record added";
>
> mysql_close($con);
>   ?>

Comment: so this would be the one code for multiple forms? Like so if I have multiple forms that can be edited it would save all of them?